# Superclass Fields Using @Builder Lombok

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

WHow to fetch the Superclass fields in the builder?

Parent:

```
package com.goomo.sso.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;


@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BaseResponseModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String status;
    private StatusMessage statusMessage;
}
```

Child:

```
package com.goomo.sso.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@ToString
public class UserRequest extends BaseResponseModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String clientName;
    private String role;
    private String groupName;
    private String userName;

    @Builder
    public UserRequest(String status, StatusMessage statusMessage, String clientName, String role, String groupName,
                       String userName) {
        super(status,statusMessage);
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.role=role;
        this.groupName=groupName;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

I couldn't get the fields of the parent class in the builder. Can you please suggest me the correct way of achieving it?

Comment: just copied your classes and I can see UserRequest.builder().status()

Comment: may be replace `@Data` with `@Getters` on `BaseResponseModel`

Comment: If you have the superclass under your control, you should consider using `@SuperBuilder`, because then you don't need that artificial manual constructor with that huge parameter list.